# Client agnostic solutions for RESTful resource security/authentication etc.?

Tags: php, apache-flex, air, rest, restful-authentication

I'm about to replace my oldfashioned sessionbased server solutions with RESTful ones.
Where can I find information about design principles concerning security, authentication etc. when moving into this stateless domain?

I need to find solutions that work with different client platforms (Flex/Air, Browser, desktop and mobile apps etc.). Right now I work with php in the server end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OAuth 2.0](http://wiki.oauth.net/OAuth-2.0)?

Comment: Thank you Peter, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is basic http authentication; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Or, if you want better security, digest

Comment: Easy, yes, but secure? Doesn't that mean transferring username and password with every request?
@troelskn: Hmm... So digest is a more secure form of http authentication..? Thanks! I'll check it out!

Comment: With https you should be ok, but of course, it's not the most secure alternative. Digest is better.

Answer (score 1):

Learn from examples like Google accounts authorization, Yahoo REST APIs etc.

Some points to notice:

- Cookies are usually used as
  out-of-band authentication tokens.
- Beware of AJAX calls failing
  authentication - if they get a 302 redirect to a form, it will be followed automatically and you'll get a 200 response with the form body as a response

Comment: Hmm... "out-of-band" - what does that mean?

Comment: "out-of-band" as opposed to inside the payload, in the sense that the authentication token is not applicative and part of a POST body for example, but rather resides in the HTTP headers and does not affect your specific applicative payload